# What controls the position of columns in grids?

Tags: magento

I've added a customer column to the Sales > Orders grid by extending prepareColumns.  What determines the order the columns are rendered in?  Is it possible to change a column's position on the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default columns are displayed in the order addColumn() was called.  You can change this with the function addColumnAfter().

The following code would add a column with an id of "category_id" after the "entity_id" column.  The 'entity_id' is the id of the column, not the "index".  99/100 times these are the same, but be aware of it.

```
$this->addColumnAfter('category_id',array(
      'header' => 'Category ID',
       'index' => 'category_id',
       'type'  => 'text',
       'width' => 70
    ),
    'entity_id'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **$this->addColumnAfter()** instead of $this->addColumn()

```
$this->addColumnAfter('customattribute', array(
      'header'=> Mage::helper('customer')->__('customattribute'),
      'index' => 'customattribute2',
      'type'  => 'options',
      'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno')->toArray(),
      'width' => '100px',
), 'before_grid_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Put **$this->sortColumnsByOrder();** at last of _prepareColumns() function.

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {

    parent::_prepareColumns();

    $this->addColumnAfter('category_id', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Category ID'),
        'index' => 'entity_id',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'width' => 70
     ), 'entity_id');

   $this->addColumnAfter('name', array(
      'header' => $this->__('Category name'),
      'sortable' => true,
       'index' => 'category_name'), 'entity_id');

   $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
  return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO none of the answers above answer the question about setting the order of an existing column, i.e. without adding it manually.

For example for placing the "SKU" column right after the "ID" one, use the following code:

```
$this->addColumnsOrder('sku', 'entity_id');
```

Where the first parameter is the ID/name of the column to be inserted after the column identified in the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `addColumnAfter` and/or `addColumnOrder` functions instead of `addColumn`.

Comment: Using both would be redudant.  By calling addColumnAfter you call addColumn() and then addColumnsOrder().  You can either do $this->addColumnAfter(...) or $this->addColumn(...) and then $this->addColumnsOrder(...).  In the end it doesn't really matter, but why do two calls if you can do it in one?

Comment: True; I poorly worded my answer. I just wanted to document that both functions are available.